# Earmarking Excel file via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to 'earmark' a file in vba? My code steps into a series of folders and imports data from every file (excel) present into a master database. The most time consuming part of the operation is opening files- currently, I add a prefix to the filename after import. The code looks for this prefix, and skips the file in the next import cycle.

Is there a more elegant and less frontend-visible way of marking files, so that VBA can recognize a completed file without opening it first?

EDIT: To clarify, the filenames are read, and the file is not processed if it has the prefix (I_). I'm looking for a way to mark the file without changing it's respective location or filename- a property not immediately apparent to other users of the database. This marking needs to persist after the code is finished, as the same files are checked again later, and possibly from multiple machines running the update code.

I can't keep a database of processed files- there are several thousand and growing. Comparing to that list would take longer than opening the file and processing it regardless of whether it has been run before.

An array of processed files wouldn't persist. I don't have issue of processing the same file multiple times in one execution, but rather, of [processing the file each time the code is executed instead of once-and-done] or [rename the file]. The latter isn't a good solution- I don't want to rename thousands of files used for reference by other people and programs.

Comment: Couldn't you keep a log of files in the database that have already been imported?  Or move the files into a "Completed Imports" folder or something like this?  Why are you opening the file to check the filename?  Couldn't you check the filename before opening the file and not open it if it has the prefix?

Comment: Move the files to a "processed" folder?

Comment: Why open the file just to get the filename? Fix your code so that it checks the file name **before** opening it. That would be pretty quick.

Comment: What format is this "master database"? Is it another Workbook, a Worksheet in same workbook, or an actual database? I'd suggest using this "database" and add a file tracker to it. Can you post a few lines from the basic code to find the files and process data from the file?

Comment: The master is another workbook. That file is sent to a customer- I can't have extraneous things in it. Additionally, the file list would take so long to loop through that simply processing every file would be faster, since there are 7,000 files and growing. Would some form of custom document properties work?

Answer (score 0):

For a small number of files, I'd add each file name to an array as they are processed, after each file name has already been checked for existence in the array.

```
If IsInArray(FileName, ProcessedFilesArray) Then

    'You processing code here

    'Add item to array when processed
    ReDim Preserve ProcessedFilesArray(1 To UBound(ProcessedFilesArray) + 1) As Variant
    ProcessedFilesArray (UBound(ProcessedFilesArray)) = FileName

End If

Function IsInArray(FileToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, FileToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

For a large number of files, I'd create a folder within the current folder for processed files, move each one there and move them back again when everything is done.